# Which tank has the most bullet speed NATURALLY?

Tags: diep.io

I hate it when people steal my kills because my bullets aren't fast enough. But I like to save my points for damage, reload, and health upgrades, good for battles, and don't put much power into bullet speed. Which would be the tank with the highest base bullet speed?

Answer (score 2):

The [Sniper](http://diepio.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper) and its upgrades will have the most bullet Speed, with the important trait

> The Sniper and its upgrades’ Bullets do not slow down when travelling through obstacles (enemy Bullets, Polygons), which may be helpful for farming. From another side, a too high Bullet Speed might be the reason the Bullet will fail to deal the max amount of damage to small and strong Polygons like the Pentagon.

In addition, the Sniper gets a natural increase to bullet speed.

> The Sniper has an increased field of vision, as well as increased Bullet Speed, Damage, and Penetration.

Upgrading into [Assassin](http://diepio.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin) for more Bullet Speed

> Upon upgrading, you receive:
>   Increased field of view
>   Increased Bullet Speed
>   Decreased Reload (rate of fire)

And finishing with the [Ranger](http://diepio.wikia.com/wiki/Ranger)

> Upgrading from the Assassin to the Ranger passively increases Field of View, Bullet Speed and Bullet Penetration while decreasing Reload and Movement Speed

Empirically, I have done some testing in the sandbox and the Ranger shots cross the map in roughly 2.84 seconds, while the Predator Tank takes closer to 3.52 seconds, even when zoomed.

Comment: good answer. But what about predator's zoom: does it give increased bullet speed?

Comment: Based on my testing in the Sandbox, Predator Zoom does not increase bullet speed, and its bullets are slower than a ranger

Comment: tanks for telling me